# Prove that **PTIME** has no complete problems with respect to linear-time reductions.

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

> Prove that **PTIME** has no complete problems with respect to
>   linear-time reductions.

I know that **PTIME** means all these problems that we can solve them in polynomial time. I suppose that I should use here time hierarchy theorem - I know it.

However, I have no idea how to solve it. I am beginner at this subject so I ask for explanation for dummy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have a PTIME-complete problem $A$, with some algorithm that runs in $O(n^k)$ time.

This means, by definition, that *every* problem in PTIME can be decided by first running a *linear-time* reduction to $A$, and then running your supposed $O(n^k)$ solver for $A$ on the result.

Can you see how this contradicts the time hierarchy theorem?

(*Hint.* How large an $A$-instance does the linear-time reduction even have time to print?)

Comment: I can see that then we can solve each problem from PTIME in $O(n+n^k) = O(n^k)$. However, I can't see a contradiction.

Comment: OK, I think that I can see: $g(n)=n^k$ is time-construable.  We know (from assumption) that each polynomial $f(n)\in O(n^k)$.  Using hierarchy theorem we can see that $DTIME(f(n))\subset DTIME(g(n)\log g(n))$. It is not possible for example for $f(n)=n^{k+1}$. Yeah ?

Comment: @HaskellFun: Possibly. I don't think I really understand your argument well enough to be sure whether it's the one I had in mind.

Comment: So show your argument, please

Comment: @HaskellFun: My argument would just be that according to the time hierarchy theorem there is a problem $B$ that can be decided in $O(n^{k+1})$ time but not in $O(n^k)$ time. But the second paragraph of my answer would amount to a decision procedure in $O(n^k)$ time, which is a contradiction.